# How do you recover Windows tilde (~) files?

Tags: windows-10, backup, recovery

I accidentally deleted my CMakeLists.txt file.  As we know, Windows (10) creates "temporary" backup files with a tilde (~) in them that appear to be in binary format. After I deleted the file, I was left with CMakeLists.txt.un~ and CMakeLists.txt~.  One would think it would be simple to take either of these file and convert it to the original text file. I searched and searched but couldn't find a way to do it.  I tried WinZip recovery tool and it couldn't find my deleted file.  Is there a way to convert either of these files back to text?  Reading up on ~ files, apparently Windows can use these files to recover the original file.  If the OS can use these files for recovery, shouldn't I be able to?

Comment: A question about recovering files is definitely not a *programming* one, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks.  I reposted on a Windows forum.  I've gotten used to SO having good answers so it's almost automatic to post here.

Comment: Just a general comment: this is a much less disruptive mistake to make if you are using git (or another VCS). You could just `git checkout HEAD CMakeLists.txt` and restore the file in its most recent committed state.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately I'm not using git for this project, but I will.